# How do I continue downloading a game in Steam while playing?

Tags: steam

I have many games on Steam and many more I will buy, but I have a problem and I hope you can point me a solution.

When I download a game, **is it possible to launch and play a single player game under Steam and continue downloading others games in the meanwhile**?

Steam stops my download as soon as I launch any game, and I am looking for a way to prevent this.

Comment: I assume that Steam thinks you want to play online and downloading will hurt your ping.

Comment: We really should be able to configure this on a per-game basis. I like to play offline because I can leave other things downloading in the meantime.

Comment: I filed a support ticket asking Valve to at least not pause downloads when they *know* the game you're launching does not support multiplayer (they obviously can't for non-Steam games or games which have both singleplayer and multiplayer). That must've been two years ago or so... ;)

Comment: Your 100 rep bounty has paid dividends, great question, @Drake!

Comment: I'm playing a single player game. That's no reason for Steam to pause  downloads.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

### Global option

You can now allow downloads during *any* gameplay from the downloads settings:

[image: Settings - Downloads - Allow downloads during gameplay]

### Per game option

You can now tell Steam to continue downloading updates/games while playing games from your games' properties. Note that this setting is *not available for non-steam games*, which will always use the global setting.

[image: Updates - Background downloads]

Comment: I presume that it's only possible to do this on a game by game basis and not make it the default for all games?

Comment: @Thunderforge the latest beta patch added a global option

Answer (score 121):

The way I do it is:

1. Pause all of the downloads manually.
2. Launch the game I want to play.
3. Alt-Tab back to Steam window, resume all downloads manually.
4. Alt-Tab back to the game and enjoy.

It seems that it only stops the download for you on launching a game. I have not found an "official" way to do it, but this way works until they give us one.

Comment: That works, I do that too.

Comment: Unfortunatly it seems to not working in recent steam.

Comment: Lies and slander, Maciej. This still works. Thanks!

Comment: @Maciej: As said by tekkitan, it still works.

Comment: @tekkitan: Maybe that fix this during 3 months? I haven't check recently but in January it didn't work for me (when I clicked resume nothing happened).

Comment: That depends on the game you're playing, some games crash on Alt-Tab.

Comment: if Alt-Tab is blocked by the game, you can try Ctrl-Alt-Del or (in Win7) Win+L (if you remember your windows user password despite using auto-login ;)

Comment: It's worth noting some games simply don't like being tabbed out of, if you come across a game like this then you will not be able to resume your downloads.

Comment: @Zommuter:  Win+M or Win+D also work sometimes.  Also, Zemm:  step 1 is not required.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft good to know, thanks. Re step 1, did that change? I remember _not_ having paused downloads which then would remain suspended despite my clicking on continue

Comment: No, for as long as I can remember *(I've been using Steam since it came out)*, I've been doing steps 2-4 to keep games downloading in the background.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore, or at least doesn't work with the Dota2 beta. The download is "suspended", not paused, so I can't resume it. I can pause it however, **then** resume it, but it gets "suspended" again after a few seconds.

Comment: I wonder if Valve is already aware of this, I can;t imagine it's too much work for them to fix this.

Comment: They could add a pop up saying that downloads reduce ping, prompting an "OK", and leave it at that.

Comment: @Codemonkey This is strange, I also play Dota 2 Beta but the old method still work for me. If I want to unpause a download when I am playing Dota 2 I just go to the progressing download and click resume. Maybe it is because I play Dota 2 in window mode, can you check if using this mode fix your issue?

Answer (score 38):

Steam used to block all downloads as soon as you launched a game. However, there is no need for a workaround anymore, thanks to the new content system: when you download a game, it is possible to launch and play a single player game under Steam and continue downloading others games in the meanwhile.

---

> **Fixed downloading new update while game is still running**

Reference: [Steam client updates](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6953/).

> In addition, the new content system will allow us to build several new features that we’ve often heard requested. Upcoming client releases will include things like download scheduling, bandwidth throttling, and prioritizing which games get downloaded first. **You’ll also be able to download an update to a game while you’re playing that game**; Steam will apply the update after you exit the game.

Reference: [Steam news](http://store.steampowered.com/news/5856/).

---

Some people are talking about downloads being suspended, but I have never experienced this problem. I suggest choosing another server and trying again if this happens to you.

---

Apparently, a new feature is coming.

[image: Option]

Comment: I see only updates are mentioned; does it also work when downloading entire games?

Comment: I have recently downloaded games that way too (Mark of the Ninja while playing L.A. Noire), but could not find an official statement about it.

Comment: Not a good update: http://store.steampowered.com/news/9951/

Answer (score 7):

1. While playing, hold Ctrl, Alt, and Del to go to pick a menu.
2. Pick the "Start Task Manager" then you can go to window.
3. Open steam then resume the downloading then click the picture where you were playing.
4. ENJOY!

Comment: This is essentially doing the same thing as in Zemm's answer but with a different way of getting out of the Steam game.

Answer (score 5):

After the game was started, you may also ALT-TAB back into steam, and then right-click and press "Pause Download" (even though it says "Paused" already), and then right-click and choose "Resume Download". I have noticed that some games do not pause your downloads, but most games do.