# Is it possible to log your Steam account into two computers at once?

Tags: steam

My gaming computer is currently downloading Napoleon: Total War and Supreme Commander 2 which I purchased on Steam, and which will take some time to complete. While this download is going on, I would like to play some of my other multiplayer games on my laptop, but I would rather not interrupt the download to do so.

Is it possible to have both computers logged in at once? I know if I was playing a single player game, I could set Steam into offline mode, then resume the download on the other computer, but this won't work for multi player games.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As several people have mentioned, it is now possible to be logged in on multiple computers at once.  Only one computer can be playing a game at a time though.  If you start a game while another computer is already in one, you will be notified and told that it will close the other game if you start.

Comment: You **can** have one in offline mode and the other online.  This is useful if the SO wants to play PopCap games while you are FPSing. ;-)

Comment: I... this is *really* weird but I just logged into Steam on two computers today. Both are online, logged in, and can use chat. Don't have time to try any games right now.

Comment: Seems the multiple logins came with the Steam Streaming update. This answer is now incorrect.

Comment: It's been possible for people in the Streaming beta for as long as the beta has been running, too.

Answer (score 8):

As of the recent Steam [Streaming](http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/) update, *yes*, it is now possible to log in to one account on multiple computers at once. You can just log in as normal; it no longer logs you out on other computers.

I'm not sure if this has been confirmed to work on multiple networks.

Answer (score 3):

As already said is not possible to be connected to Steam with the same account in more than 1 computer at time.

But maybe this QA can solve your problem: [How to continue downloading a game in Steam while playing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/how-to-continue-downloading-a-game-in-steam-while-playing)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to be logged onto Steam in two computers if one of the computers is downloading or playing a game online. One of the Steam accounts must be in offline mode to be logged into both at once.

Answer (score -1):

Just to make sure there's a more current response: I spent about 5 months being able to be logged in on two computers at once. It suddenly stopped allowing that yesterday. I did install a game on the second computer for the first time about a week ago, before that I just streamed to it occasionally, so maybe there's something to the download/online multiplayer thing.

Comment: and I just signed out of both, and logged in again and this time it worked. To be clear, for the past few days, the computer that I keep on and logged in all the time would be forced into offline mode (without restarting steam) any time I logged in or woke up the other computer. There would be no sign in button in the friends list, and the bottom of the main window would say "No Connection"

Comment: Sounds like a bug, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I did start once the same game on two computers simultaneously. The one of them starts the game normally and the second one gives pop-up message asking me if I want to stream the game that is already started?. So, I understand that in the future if I may be streaming i will use this option.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the existing answers.