# Is it possible to get Steam to continue downloading a game while I'm playing?

Tags: steam, dota-2, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I continue downloading a game in Steam while playing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/how-do-i-continue-downloading-a-game-in-steam-while-playing)

This question has been asked before, but it's outdated and the solution no longer applies: [How do I continue downloading a game in Steam while playing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2857/4536)

The answer used to be just starting the game, then swapping over to the Steam client and manually resume the downloads. This is no longer possible, since the downloads aren't paused, they are "suspended", so resuming is not an option. I can *pause* the download, **then** resume it, but it just gets suspended again after a few seconds, even when I don't resume the minimized game.

#### So did Valve "fix" the old workaround? If so, did they implement another way of doing it?

---

I'm playing Dota 2 full screen on Windows 7 while trying to download GTA IV in the background.

Comment: I believe the better way to go about this is to start a bounty on the old question and choose the "Answers are out of date" reason. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate so it will be closed. A better way to approach the problem of outdated answers is indeed to set a bounty, as Kareen noted, and in this case I went ahead and set the bounty on the other question for you. I also have [an old meta post listing other ways to handle this problem of incorrect / outdated answers](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/what-can-i-do-if-the-asker-accepts-an-answer-that-is-incorrect/5141#5141), if you're interested - and I see you have indeed already left a comment on the accepted answer there :)