# How to pause Steam downloads?

Tags: steam

I would like to pause a download on steam, however when I right click on the game, there is no option to 'Pause Downloading'. Note that I don't wish to delete it, just pause it.

So, how can I pause it without closing Steam?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of viewing the games through your "Installed" or "All" games dropdown, select "Downloads" where you can manage all downloads Steam is performing. Here you can pause and resume or reorder any active or pending downloads.

Additionally, launching a Steam game will, [by default, pause all current downloads](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/how-do-i-continue-downloading-a-game-in-steam-while-playing?rq=1).

Comment: additionally, launching a steam game will also pause all downloads.

Comment: @horatio Good point - added.

Comment: FYI, on Windows, if you alt+tab out of the game and go back to the Steam client, you can unpause the download if you like, and then go play your game. Steam will then download in the background while you play.

Comment: You can also select resume downloads when playing a specific(selected) game

Answer (score 1):

Go to steam "Big Picture Mode". Click anything that is being downloaded (the one who's not supposed to be downloading). Click "Downloading". You'll see the pause button in there!

Comment: Thank you! They seem to have hidden the pause option in the standard view now.